# Convergence and maximum of $f_n(x)=xn^{\alpha}e^{-nx},x\in[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Given $f_n(x)=xn^{\alpha}e^{-nx},x\in[0,\infty)$, how do I

$b)$ prove each $f_n(x)$ has a max value and find it, and

$c)$ find the $\alpha$ for which $f_n$ converges uniformly?

All I've been able to do so far for $(b)$ is to take $f'_n(x)=n^\alpha e^{-nx}(1-nx)$ has critical points at $1/n$, and $f''_n(x)=n^{\alpha+1}e^{-nx}(nx-2)$, but plugging in the critical points doesn't help me here. For $(c)$, I have $f=n$, and I know I need to make use of the maximums I found in $(b)$, but I don't know what to do beyond that.

Edit: (b) was just a silly blunder, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding exactly what you're doing, but the possible places where $f$ has a maximum are boundary point and points where $f'_n = 0$. So those are $x= 0$ and $x = \frac 1 n$. Since $f_n(0) = 0$ for all $n$, the maxima must occur at $x = \frac 1 n$.  Indeed, $f''_n(1/n) < 0$, so those points are maxima. Then $$f_n(1/n) = \frac{n^{\alpha - 1}}{e}.$$ This resolves (b).

For all $x \ge 0$, we have $f_n(x) \le \frac{n^{\alpha - 1}}{e}$ which shows that $f_n \to 0$ uniformly if the right hand side goes to zero. So to answer (c), we see $f_n$ goes uniformly to zero if $n^{\alpha -1} \to 0$ so we need $\alpha < 1$.

Comment: No, $\alpha = 1/2$ gives $n^{-1/2}$ in the numerator, which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$.